# how to plot data from csv file?

Tags: microsoft-access, csv

I'm looking for a way to plot data imported from a `.csv` file much like the pivot chart view of an Microsoft Access table.

I'm just having problems with Microsoft Access 2010 and was wondering if there's an alternative ?

Update following comments:

I need something thats capable of handling a large dataset (10's of thousands of records).
the data is mostly numerical it represents the parameters and result of a computation that i'm performing, i need to plot statistical information (avgerage/variance etc.) of the result as a function of different parameter values.

The main features i'm looking for is the ability to easily import data from a csv file and later to manipulate it and create charts, preferably through a gui.

i tried MS Access 2010. i have excel but i was afraid it couldn't datasets of that magnitude.

Comment: What kind of plot do you want exactly? Can you give some sample data and a quick sketch of how you want it to look like? Which tools have you tried? Do you have Excel at hand?

Comment: @slhck thanks for your commment, i updated the question to respond.

Comment: I believe [R](http://www.r-project.org/) is what best suites your requirements. Importing huge CSV data, getting statistical information and plotting data is what it's mainly used for. It takes a while to get used to though.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you want to produce this sort of thing:

[image: Example chart from MS]

It's not GUI but I suggest looking at [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) or maybe [r](http://www.r-project.org/)

[image: Example from GnuPlot]
Example graph from GnuPlot website. Examples [here](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_4.2/histograms.html) detailed script [here](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_4.2/histograms.6.gnu) and  data from [here](http://212.182.0.171/cgi-bin/dwww/usr/share/doc/gnuplot-doc/examples/immigration.dat) I suspect.

If you must have a GUI, you could perhaps have a look at http://sourceforge.net/projects/jgp/ etc.

For very large datasets (more than can easily be accomodated in RAM) it is probably best to pre-process the data to obtain the summarised values you want to plot. I'd use Perl for this but there is no shortage of tools for the task. Pick one that suits you.